# Why can't compilers optimize successive unordered_map lookups with the same key?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, compiler-optimization

As a human it's fairly nice to write stuff with a general idiom (pseudocode, written python-style so nobody can confuse it for real code)

```
if map.contains(key):
  do_thing(map[key])
else:
  do_other_thing(map, key)
```

However it seems like `g++` is unable to optimize successive lookups into a `std::unordered_map` with the same key; the methods

```
int f(std::unordered_map<int, int> & map, int key, int defaultValue)
{
  if(map.find(key) == map.end()) { return defaultValue; }

  return map.at(key);
}
```

and

```
int g(std::unordered_map<int, int> & map, int key, int defaultValue)
{
  auto it = map.find(key);

  return (it == map.end()) ? defaultValue : it->second;
}
```

should have identical behavior, but neither `g++` nor `clang` generate identical code at `-O3`: https://godbolt.org/z/qzW9PjWde

In fact it looks like `clang` even generates code to handle the event that the call to `at()` throws, which is impossible in this context.  (Update: MSVC actually generates similar-looking code in both cases, but it involves a bunch of `calls` as opposed to the completely inlined code generated by `g++` and `clang`.)

Is there some subtlety that I'm missing here that makes these functions non-identical?  I can use the second idiom in my code, or write wrappers that return a `bool` indicating whether or not they modified a value passed by reference, but both of these seem less readable than the first approach.

(Of course I'm aware that in many cases the cost of doing an extra lookup doesn't matter.)

---

**EDIT**: In the comments and in answers people are operating under the assumption that I'm asking about a `std::unordered_map`-specific optimization.  I'm not.  Let's write, in pseudocode, what each of these methods looks like:

```
  map.find(key) const:
    let bucket := storage[hash(key) % size]
    let it := bucket.find(key)
    if it != bucket.end:
      return it
    else:
      return end

  map.at(key) const:
    let bucket := storage[hash(key) % size]
    let it := bucket.find(key)
    if it != bucket.end:
      return it->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
```

so if you consider a method that looks like

```
get(map, key, default):
  if map.find(key) != map.end:
    return map.at(key)
  else
    return default
```

then just plugging in the definitions we have:

```
get(map, key, default):
  let bucket := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
  let it := bucket.find(key)
  if it != bucket.end:
    let find_result := it
  else:
    let find_result := map.end

  if find_result != map.end:
    let bucket2 := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
    let it2 := bucket2.find(key)
    if it2 != bucket2.end:
      return it2->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
  else
    return default
```

Since every single method called on `map` is `const`, and the value of `key` does not change either, the compiler should have no trouble deducing that `bucket2` is the same as `bucket`.  This is a standard optimization that we know compilers can and often will do:

```
get(map, key, default):
  let bucket := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
  let it := bucket.find(key)
  if it != bucket.end:
    let find_result := it
  else:
    let find_result := map.end

  if find_result != map.end:
    let it2 := bucket.find(key)
    if it2 != bucket.end:
      return it2->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
  else
    return default
```

Next, since everything we do to `bucket` is const, `it2` is the same as `it`, so we have

```
get(map, key, default):
  let bucket := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
  let it := bucket.find(key)
  if it != bucket.end:
    let find_result := it
  else:
    let find_result := map.end

  if find_result != map.end:
    if it != bucket.end:
      return it->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
  else
    return default
```

Again, a totally normal optimization that compilers do all the time.  Next, consolidate the two conditionals:

```
get(map, key, default):
  let bucket := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
  let it := bucket.find(key)
  if it != bucket.end:
    if it != bucket.end:
      return it->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
  else:
    return default
```

Finally, if we have a block that looks like

```
  if it != bucket.end:
    if it != bucket.end:
      return it->second
    else:
      throw ValueNotFoundException
```

then of course this simplifies to

```
  if it != bucket.end:
    return it->second
```

-- again, a totally prosaic optimization -- and we end up with

```
get(map, key, default):
  let bucket := map.storage[map.hash(key) % map.size]
  let it := bucket.find(key)
  if it != bucket.end:
    return it->second
  else:
    return default
```

(If you're skeptical about compilers' ability to do these optimizations, note that both g++ and clang were easily able to deduce that this method couldn't possibly throw, so they're doing *most* of the above already...)

As far as I can see there is nothing preventing the compiler from doing these optimizations, so I wanted to make sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234837/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-mclaury-why-cant-compilers-optimize-successive).

Answer (score -1):

The compiler has to be able to guarantee that its optimisations will behave as if the original code had been executed.

The compiler doesn't necessarily understand that `find` and `at` with the same key will return the same value (especially as they don't even return the same value, one returns an iterator, the other a reference). `std::map` isn't anything special as far as the language is concerned, the compiler will treat it as any other class.

Whilst compiler vendors could encode these special cases for known standard library classes it'd probably not be worth the effort and complexity to cover all the various use cases which would be better covered by writing better code. Even if these optimisations were implemented they'd likely only work with the standard library they're designed for, e.g. if clang added `std::map` optimisations based on libc++ those optimisations probably wouldn't work for libstdc++ or the MSVC standard library and would have to be re-implemented for each of them.

Comment: "There is no guarantee that map hasn't been modified by some other thread between the calls to `find` and `at`."  This is not how C++ works.  The standard explicitly allows the optimizer to make that assumption, and this sort of assumption is used _very_ aggressively by all mainstream compilers.

Comment: "Whilst compiler vendors could encode these special cases for known standard library classes it'd probably not be worth the effort " Agreed, but this shouldn't require a special optimization as far as I can see.  Just needs to do basic things like "the result of the same constexpr function called on the same arguments is the same," "two consecutive reads from the same memory address give the same results," etc.

Comment: *There is no guarantee that map hasn't been modified by some other thread between the calls to find and at.* The standard actually states that all code is ran if there is only a single thread. That's why we have to manually ensure we don't have any data races using explicit synchronization techniques.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think there may be an exception for initialization of static variables.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not sure about that.  If you are talking about the static initialization order fiasco, that is more a compilation issue then anything else as we have no guarantee on the order of compilation of TU's or how they are linked together.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury `std::map` isn't `constexpr` though and determining that two consecutive traversals of a tree inside `std::map` is probably just beyond current optimisers

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I'm talking about `std::unordered_map`, not `std::map`.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury `std::unordered_map` isn't `constexpr` either and probably has an equally complex implementation